# The request parameters are empty after the loading of the Laravel kernel

Tags: php, laravel, http, request, get

When I type a URL www.exemple/test/?var1=value1, I can't get the request parameters in Laravel 8.

When I dump the PHP `$_GET` variable in the controller, it returns an empty array, as well as `$_REQUEST` and also the Laravel `$request->all()`.

`$request->query('var1')` and `$request->input('var1')` return NULL too.

The QUERY_STRING in `$_SERVER` variable is empty, but REDIRECT_QERY_STRING has the parameters.

And when I dump the `$_GET` variable in public/index.php before `$response = $kernel->handle( $request = Request::capture() )->send();` it has the parameters as well as `$_REQUEST` and QUERY_STRING in `$_SERVER` variable.

I ran `composer update`, And there is no .htaccess in the public folder, the Apache log file has no error, and there are no redirections in access.log of Apache too, and the laravel.log also has no error about this issue.

Locally and in the testing server works fine, but not in the production server, the same code and configuration are used.

Any ideas please ?

**UPDATE :**

There are other applications on the server that work fine.

Comment: sounds like your webserver is misconfigured

Comment: @lagbox the GET parameters are successfully admissible in index.php before the load of the kernel, and there is other application running on the server without any problem

Comment: @lagbox you were right, turns out that for the production server, there is some RewriteRule should be added to Apache in VirtualHost of the project :
 `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt|\.jpeg)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L] `